# Как работает приведенный код

Tags: java

не могу понять как работает алгоритм считывания.
Не понятно именно это :

```
while((i=fin.read())!=-1)
{
    System.out.print((char)i);
}
```

Как это работает? В обучалке которую разбираю я, ничего внятно не сказано.
Не понятно что происходит в этих скобках `(i=fin.read())`. Зачем мы вообще сюда i вписываем? Мы передаём считанные байты в i? А не должно это быть написанным в `{}` скобках? `while(fin.read()!=-1)` это понятно, пока с файла считываются байты, он будет выполнять следующие действия. 
И вот тут второй момент. Как работает это?

```
System.out.print((char)i);
```

Что это за запись вообще?
((char)i) Что здесь происходит? Если i это считанные байты, то что тут делает char? Он преобразует байты в char? А ПОЧЕМУ ЭТО ТАК ТУПО НАПИСАНО?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Program {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try(FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("C://SomeDir//notes.txt"))
    {
        System.out.printf("File size: %d bytes \n", fin.available());

        int i=-1;
        while((i=fin.read())!=-1){

            System.out.print((char)i);
        }   
    }
    catch(IOException ex){

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

Comment: Когда-то давно я был начинающим программистом и считал, что некоторые вещи тупо написаны. А потом изучил учебник, поднабрался опыта и понял, что это я тупо читал.

Comment: Для того что бы понять почему `int` можно привести к типу `char`, вы должны хотя бы прочитать о том какие типы данных имеются, и чем один от другого целочисленного типа отличается.

Comment: То что не сказано в обучалке надо додумывать самому, или же читать другую обучалку. Не следует задавать слишком много вопросов, чтобы задать вопрос нужно сосредоточиться на конкретной проблеме и привести код, который пытался её решить.

Answer (score 2):

В этой строке `while ((i = fin.read()) != -1)` происходит одновременное считывание байта в переменную `i` и проверка результата на неравенство `-1`. Это эквивалентно

```
int i = fin.read();
while (i != -1) {
    System.out.print((char) i);
    i = fin.read();
}
```

Но как по мне это не эстетично выглядит и нужно лишний раз перед циклом считывать байт.
Из той же серии - можно в одной строке присвоить переменной значение и вернуть в качестве результата метода:

```
...
return i = 5;
```

По поводу `System.out.print((char)i);`
 Методы класса FIS, читающие байты, возвращают значения этих байтов в виде целочисленного значения `int`. Почему не `byte` или `char`? Потому что кроме самого байта нужно еще вернуть `-1` когда достигнут конец стрима. Поэтому для проверки `END OF FILE` используют проверку на `-1`, а если не конец, то переводим считанное целое значение байта в `byte` или `char`, как в данном случае (видимо, читаем текстовый файл, который можно вывести в консоль посимвольно).

На будущее - когда дойдете до метода `int read(byte b[])`, то он возвращает тоже целое число, но оно уже будет представлять не сам байт, а количество считанных байт в заданный буфер...

Вывод - изучайте мат. часть!